# return Set of lists from out of function: python

Tags: python, list, append, return-value, xlrd

Method `collectInfoFromXLS()` extracts all the contents which are under `quotes ('')` from given XLS file, and  puts in an `List`.

```
class ExtractInfo(object):

    def collectInfoFromXLS():
        workbookPath = config.get('TestCaseFileURL','XLSpath')
        workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(workbookPath)
        SheetPath = config.get('TesCaseSheetName','Sheet1')
        worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_name(SheetPath)
        numOfRows = worksheet.nrows - 1
        curr_row = 0
        row1 = []
        row2 = []
        while curr_row < numOfRows:
           curr_row += 1
           row2 = []
           row = worksheet.row(curr_row)
           for value2 in re.findall(r"'(.*?)'", str(row)):
                row2.append(value2)
           return row2
```

I get output of this method when I print `row2` is like

```
['', 'MUC-EC-099_SC-Memory-01_TC-1', 'Description1.', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
['', 'MUC-EC-099_SC-Memory-01_TC-2', 'Description2', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
......
```

I want to call this method from outside of the class, like

```
Classobject = ExtractInfo(object)
print Classobject.collectInfoFromXLS()
```

So that I could get every rows exactly like `print` inside method,
I don't want to append `rows2` inside one more list, because it makes problem while retrieving.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @DanielRoseman: he wants to magically return a sequence of lists without creating a sequence.

Comment: Exactly @MartijnPieters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python methods can return only **one** result at a time.

That one result *can* be a list of lists; just return a larger list, and *loop* over the result:

```
result = []
row2 = []
while curr_row < numOfRows:
   curr_row += 1
   row2 = []
   row = worksheet.row(curr_row)
   for value2 in re.findall(r"'(.*?)'", str(row)):
        row2.append(value2)
   result.append(row2)
return result
```

and:

```
for row in Classobject.collectInfoFromXLS():
    print row
```

A more advanced technique would be to turn your method into a generator function, and yield the rows, one by one. You'd still loop over the method. To make the function a generator, use a `yield` expression; you can no longer use  `return` with a value once you make it a generator:

```
def collectInfoFromXLS():
    workbookPath = config.get('TestCaseFileURL','XLSpath')
    workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(workbookPath)
    SheetPath = config.get('TesCaseSheetName','Sheet1')
    worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_name(SheetPath)
    numOfRows = worksheet.nrows - 1
    curr_row = 0
    row2 = []
    while curr_row < numOfRows:
       curr_row += 1
       row2 = []
       row = worksheet.row(curr_row)
       for value2 in re.findall(r"'(.*?)'", str(row)):
            row2.append(value2)
       yield row2
```

You *still* have to loop over the output:

```
for row in Classobject.collectInfoFromXLS():
    print row
```

only now `Classobject.collectInfoFromXLS()` returns a generator object instead of a list, and you can loop over that object only once.